# Anyone have Canon MF4890dw with cndrvcups 2.80 working on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, printing, canon

I recently upgraded to 14.04 with cndrvcups-common and cndrvcups-ufr2-us 2.80-1.  When I print a test page or PDF from evince (and presumable other print modes as well), /usr/bin/cnpkmoduleufr2 cpu use goes to 100% until killed (at least 15 minutes). This used to work in 13.10 with 2.70. (I suspect this is a problem with the driver and has nothing to do with the ubuntu upgrade.)

strace shows apparently endless repeated lines like this:

```
read(7, "", 4)                          = 0
read(7, "", 4)                          = 0
read(7, "", 4)                          = 0
...
```

Before I invest time on trying to recompile cndrvcups from scratch... does anyone have this working or at least have the same symptoms?

-Reece

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same symptoms. While running Ubuntu 14.04 with the Canon UFR2 drivers (ver 2.80) and trying to print a test page, cnpkmoduleufr2 spins at 100% cpu usage and nothing gets printed. I got the same results as you did when a ran strace on the pid corresponding to the cnpkmoduleufr2 process. Rich

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get my Canon LBP printer to run under Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Masayuki Sakura at Canon, the maintainer listed in the Debian package. His reply:

> We were able to reproduce the same kind of problem as the issue you
>   reported. ... could you install
>   32-bit version of libstdc++6 with the following command and perform
>   print test.
>
> # apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
>
> By the way, I have checked our user's guide and readme file, but this
>   notification is not described. We will add this notification to the
>   next version of the driver.

Indeed, this solved the issue.

Thank you to Masayuki for his prompt customer support.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thanks for providing the answer. You can accept your own answer if you want to and it will mark this as solved.

Comment: @reece You got a response from Canon? Do you have an email address for Masayuki Sakura? Or which address did you complain to?

Comment: @bain sup-debian@list.canon.co.jp, which I got from the maintainer entry in the .deb. BTW, Masayuki was incredibly prompt and helpful. I've seen numerous jabs at Canon support, but my experience was exceptional.

Comment: @Reece I hope so, I just sent them a link to the [300+ questions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/canon) asking how to get their printers working with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded and installed the Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V300_us_EN drivers from Canon's website and my mf4890dw printer is working now.  I could not get it to work with the V280 drivers, but the newer V300 drivers do work!