# Canon-LBP2900 printer not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing, canon

I could not get cannon lbp printer to work on ubuntu (14.04) after trying everything possible on the internet.

Packages intsalled - `cndrvcups-capt_2.60-1_i386.deb` and `cndrvcups-common_2.60-1_i386.deb`

The Printer adds job the queue and fails to print silently.

Here is the cups error log -

```
ipt@ipt-G41D3C:~$ tail -f /var/log/cups/error_log
E [12/May/2014:11:33:22 +0000] [Client 19] Returning IPP client-error-document-format-not-supported for Print-Job (ipp://localhost/printers/Generic-text-only) from localhost
E [12/May/2014:12:01:30 +0000] **Canon-LBP2900**: File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstocapt" not available: No such file or directory
E [12/May/2014:12:01:30 +0000] Canon-LBP2900: File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstocapt" not available: No such file or directory
E [12/May/2014:12:01:30 +0000] Canon-LBP2900: File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstocapt" not available: No such file or directory
E [12/May/2014:13:59:53 +0000] [Job 13] Unable to send data to printer.
E [12/May/2014:14:04:53 +0000] [Job 13] Stopping unresponsive job.
E [12/May/2014:14:06:37 +0000] [Job 14] Unable to send data to printer.
```

[As you can see in the snapshot printer is not able to process the print jobs.](http://postimg.org/image/fj6jvz68r/)

Comment: "after trying everything possible on the internet." https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon ?

Comment: Not yet. Let me try this.

Comment: This might be worth a shot too: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190 It is about the packages you installed. But see the extra commands you need to issue. If those are wrongly entered it will not work. (follow the 13.10 notes)

Comment: After configuring with instruction here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190 my printer shows job status as complete without actually printing.

Comment: Tried https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon. I can't make it work either.

Comment: Please report the bug to Canon; the more people who complain, the more likely the bug is to get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my LBP 2900 printer to work on ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit. I followed the instructions posted here: [Can't get my Canon LBP printer to run under Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04).

There seems to be some fault with CAPT. So to get the printer to work I had to use the commands given here:" [Making Canon LBP6000 printer work under Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473728/making-canon-lbp6000-printer-work-under-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit)
I used the kill commands (as given in update 2 of the link above) to stop capt and restart it.

also captstatusui command is handy while printing to check for any errors: sudo captstatusui -P LBP2900

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest driver from this [link](http://support-th.canon-asia.com/contents/TH/EN/0100459601.html) and install the debs files under 32-bit_Driver/Debian using

first install cndrvcups-common-x.xx-x.i386, then install cndrvcups-capt-x.xx-x.i386

you will also see detailed document under folder Doc/guide-capt-2.7xUK, open the index.html