# Making Canon LBP6000 printer work under Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, printing, canon

Previously, [I have successfully used](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174474/installing-canon-lbp6000-in-ubuntu-12-04) this Canon LBP6000 printer under Ubuntu 12.04 (32-bit). Recently, I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit). Already several hours have been wasted making this printer work under this system, without success.

(I have already seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp6000-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04). But thought it better to post a new one since my observations are too long to fit as a comment. There is a similar issue [in this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463674/ubuntu-14-04-cannot-print-through-canon-mf8200-series-printer).)

**Steps So Far**

- The [Radu script](http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/) did not work. Got something in the line of "ccp, unknown URI".
- Downloaded and installed the [latest driver from Canon](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html).
- Installed the `.deb` files found in `Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN/64-bit_Driver/Debian`

  sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-c*

(Did not use the [Michael PPA](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-stable) since I was actually downloading the latest driver from Canon site.)

- Installation went without any problem.
- Started CUPS in a browser. `http://localhost:631/`. The printer was automatically detected as Canon LBP6000/LBP6018. Moved forward and selected Canon LBP6000/LBP6018 CAPT (US) as the driver. Got it installed. The printer URI is shown as `usb://Canon/LBP6000/LBP6018?serial=0000B1C4I3GU`
- Now, when I try printing a test page, the CUPS window says that "Sending Data to Printer". In about a minute, this job is shown as completed, though nothing gets printed.

---

The [official Ubuntu page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190) lists LBP6000/LBP6018
as a supported printer with driver
CNCUPSLBP6018CAPTK.ppd
under Ubuntu
13.10 (64bit)/12.10/12.04 (32bit). So, previously, there has been success with
64-bit versions.

---

**UPDATE 1**

As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/467982/82650), executed `find . -name \*.so\* -exec ldd {} \;|grep not`
in the extracted driver directory. Got an output in the line of

> ```
> libcncaptnpm.so.1 => not found
> libstdc++.so.6 => not found
> ```

Executed `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6`. Now the message is reduced to the one
for `libcncaptnpm` only. Do not know how to install this one. `apt-cache search libcncaptnpm` returns an empty answer.

Any chance I can directly use the `libcnaccm.so.1.0` file found under `Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN/Src/cndrvcups-capt-2.60-1/libs`?

---

**UPDATE 2 (SOLVED)**

I followed the procedure described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/464334/82650).  *(Though I had downloaded the drivers directly from [Canon site](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html).)*

Now my printer prints again. Big sigh of relief.

The next printer I will buy will *not* be a Canon. The hassle I had to go through was perhaps acceptable twenty years back. In this era, I will want my printer to simply plug-in and work.

***Observations***

When I submit the first print job in a login session, it waits. The queue says, Processing since ..... Then I need to kill the `ccpd` and `captmoncnabc` processes and
start the `ccpd` daemon again.

Wonder why I have to do it.

Actually, I made a script for that.

```
#!/bin/bash

pkill -9 -x ccpd
pkill -9 -x captmoncnabc
/etc/init.d/ccpd start
/etc/init.d/ccpd status
```

Comment: See my answer to [Can't get my Canon LBP printer to run under Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp6000-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @bain Your suggested method worked. Flawlessly. Also, your answer is full of insights. This was particularly delightful. Perhaps you can answer the observations at the end of my **UPDATE 2**.

Comment: Sometimes ccpd hangs. I do not know why, but I suspect it is a bug. I use the same process (kill -9, start) when this happens. You could try to `strace` ccpd to debug what it is waiting for (if anything). You could  try asking Canon - there is a contact address for the drivers: sup-debian@list.canon.co.jp

Answer (score 2):

I followed Masroor/bain instructions; after installing EVERY SINGLE (hidden) DEPENDENCY, I was able to get it to work, but ran into the "kill ccpd once every boot" issue.

If you go [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190) and look at the very end of the page, they say:

Only one ccpd process running after system startup
For normal operation two ccpd processes should be running in a system. The ccpd daemon depends on running cups daemon before forking the second process. You can use the following method to workaround the problem:

1. Enable the cups init script (update-rc.d cups defaults).
2. Instruct the ccpd init script to run after the cups init (update-rc.d ccpd defaults 99), or add "sleep 10 && /etc/init.d/ccpd start" in /etc/rc.local script.

I removed all runlevels for ccpd and added the sleep command to rc.local.

Answer (score 1):

Here are scripts that helped me with LBP6000, however it is in russian.

http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/canon_capt

There is a downloads section on the page. Then you choose printer model and install it. You'll probably better use translator, but it is worth it.

Comment: Got rid of that annoying printer. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There may be one more problem with installing this printer. After having done all above mentioned, I still couldn't get my printer working. The problem was with registering printer in ccpdadmin. The command:

```
# ccpdadmin -p LBP6000 -o /dev/usb/lp0
```

written here:  [Can't get my Canon LBP printer to run under Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04/464334#464334) was wrong for me. Because in my PC there was only /dev/usb/lp1 instead of /dev/usb/lp0 noticed in that command. It cost me 2 days to figure that out.