# how to make canon LBP 6000 printer work on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: printing, canon

how can i make my printer (canon LBP 6000) work on ubuntu 14.04 ?
should i seek help from a programmer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get my Canon LBP printer to run under Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: you can follow these steps :

http://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Install the Cannon LBP printer driver `printer-driver-cjet`:

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-cjet
```

then use the printer with the application `Printers`

Comment: no, did not work for me, there is a lot of "canon LBP printers" in the list but not LBP 6000 T_T