# captstatusui -P LBP3300 Error in `captstatusui': double free or corruption

Tags: printing, canon

I tried installing Canon LBP3300 printer in ubuntu 14.04 and I am getting the following error

```
captstatusui -P LBP3300
Error in `captstatusui': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000175f5e0 ***
```

Aborted (core dumped)

and the printer stops.

Comment: how do you install ?

Comment: I have followed the instructions given in the following link http://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04. When I run the captstatusui I get a window and when I give print command I get the error posted. By the way I was using ubuntu 14.04 64 bit system

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the installation instructions you followed:

`captstatusui includes an unbounded call to strcpy in cnsktmodule.c which fails with error aborted *** buffer overflow detected *** on some system`

This is a bug. Please report this bug to Canon support, email: sup-debian@list.canon.co.jp