# PDF are printed as black page

Tags: printing, pdf

I succeded in getting working my Canon LBP6000 on XUbuntu 14.04. (Following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04)). Now the printer works almost fine.

My problem is that PDF files are printed as black pages. More precisely, the output is a black rectangle sormounted by some fuzzy lines.

It happens independently of the PDF reader I try to use (built-in Chromium reader or Evince). I tried printing PDF into another PDF and the result is fine. Ghostscript is correctly installed and test pages are correctly printed too. Other filetypes like *djvu* are correctly printed, so it appears as a specifically PDF issue.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

**UPDATES.** Also PostScript files behave like PDF.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial solution**. Canon CAPT drivers README suggestes it's better to use Acrobat Reader for printing PDF files. This is a working, not fully satisfactory, solution. It should be noted one has to set "*Let the printer determine colors*" in "Advanced" tab (left bottom corner of the printing acroread form), otherwise the output will have swapped colours: black for the background, white for the text.

**Remark 1.** So far I've not yet tested whether other readers print well since I've wasted a fair amount of toner and I need it now. Since it's quite annoying being compelled to use Acrobat Reader (which has a ridiculous printing system for multiple pages), please let me know about your experiences with other readers.

**Remark 2.** Installing acroread do not cause changes in default Ghostscript driver nor in available Ghostscript drivers.

**Remark 3.** acroread doesn't support opening PostScript files, so I couldn't verify whether issue is fixed for them.