# Canon LBP 3150 not running in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: printing, 14.10, canon

I've downloaded the "Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN.tar.gz" file. But unable to install it properly. What are the steps to install LBP 3150 in Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get my Canon LBP printer to run under Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I've followed those steps. But the printer had some problem. Now that it's running I'll try again. Thx