# Canon LBP6000 printer not working with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing, canon, multiarch

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I am new to Linux and my Canon LBP6000 printer isn't working with Ubuntu 14.04.

[I tried **this** question's answer as solution, but I didn't work.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04?lq=1)

I tried the following commands:

```
# amd64 only
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libxml2:i386 zlib1g:i386 libpopt0:i386
```

and got an error:

```
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/arch-new': Permission denied
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Add `sudo` to the begginings of the comands, this asks for `admin`access (called `root` in ubuntu) so `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` enter pass word `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libxml2:i386 zlib1g:i386 libpopt0:i386` any more issues please make a question, also see the manual for explanations of all this http://manpages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using `sudo` (`root` or administrative) rights:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libxml2:i386 zlib1g:i386 libpopt0:i386
```

In the most cases you need `sudo` to become root access to install software in your system.

Comment: As you're a reputation 11 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

As I know all printers have been already installed in Linux systems. Just try that;

0-Your cable must be plugged,

1-open your system settings,

2-search printers,

3-a new window will open,

4-just click that button "add", (maybe something different,I am not using a different language not English)

5-find your printer.

That will be work. (Work for me every-time for every printers)