# How to install Canon LBP330 in Lts 16.04

Tags: networking, printing, canon

Greeting from Suborna.
In my office I am the only person using Ubuntu. My network has Canon LBP3300. But I can't install any driver for it and get anything printed.

I am new to Ubuntu. So, if possible please guide me completely.

Regards

Comment: Ok try this `question` [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04) see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip3300series

Official [page](http://ubuntuportal.com/2011/12/how-to-install-canon-printer-driver-for-linux-ubuntu.html)

Any difficulties try this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04). Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks George for your prompt reply.
Finally I have done it using smb://  and now it is fine.

Comment: glad to have been of help.