# Printing Error, Canon LBP6000

Tags: printing, canon

I've installed Canon LBP6000 with [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/q/463289/1147664), but I'm getting this error:

**ccp send_data error**

What Should I do? Since I'm a newcomer to the Linux world, I don't even know where to start for debugging.

I'm using Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. It's been days since I'm searching how to get it to work, but I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canon is known for lousy Linux support.

Their driver here https://www.canondriver.net/canon-i-sensys-lbp6000-driver-linux/#comments appears to have had problems even back with Ubuntu 18.04 if you look at the one comment there.

https://www.canondriver.net/canon-lbp2900b-driver-linux/

> Driver Software Details Canon i-SENSYS LBP2900B
>
> File name: linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz
>
> Release date: 09/04/2015
>
> File version: V2.71

A 6 years old printer driver? That's not a good sign.

If you Google around, you will find that other users had problems with that printer on various other Linux distributions as well, and those threads tend to end in recommendations what other printer to get where the maker does care about Linux users.

You could ask Canon at that web address, but I wouldn't get my hopes too high.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news...